# Indexing is occuring in Qt Creator in the background frequently

Tags: qt-creator

I'm using Qt 5.0.2, I have noticed a progress bar named **indexing**, which is appearing frequently. Could anyone help me what is happening in the backgroud?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean QtCreator indexer ?

This task is launched each time the project file is edited but can also run regularly.
You can find a discussion a bout it on Qt forums : http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/11581

I think the indexer browse your project files to resolve includes path. But there are certainly many other features.